# @lvalue NSMutableArray' is not convertible to 'SequenceType'

Tags: ios, swift, loops, nsmutablearray

I'm triying to looping through `NSMutableArray` in Swift. But why I'm getting this error in simple case like this :

```
// note : `responseObject:AnyObject!`

var temp = NSMutableArray(array: responseObject as! [AnyObject])

for a:NSDictionary in temp { // @lvalue NSMutableArray' is not convertible to 'SequenceType'
    // Do some stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Define temp as var temp:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array:responseObject as! [AnyObject]) i think this will help you

Comment: Actually No, it's already automatically converted by this NSMutableArray(...), you don't need to say temp:NSMutableArray.

Comment: responseObject is array or Dictionary?

Comment: it's an array and returning from AFNetworking (not using Alamofire in my project yet), and I check this if responseObject != nil && responseObject.count != 0 ,

Comment: Where is the problem, just remove the `:NSDictionary`.  `for a in temp {...}` works.

Comment: problem is that your temp:NSMutablearray contain array ! and you are checking for dictionary in temp! right??

Comment: @luk2302 it's work like that, but can you explain because every object in loop will be NSDictionary. After removing compiler force me to use "a" like this "a as! [NSObject : AnyObject]"

Comment: also @luk2302 can you write this as answer format for me to sign as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var temp = NSMutableArray(array: responseObject as! [AnyObject])

for a in (temp as NSArray as! [NSDictionary]) {
    // 'a' is of type 'NSDictionary'
    // Do some stuff here...
}
```